# How to fix the toolbar to the top in activity with the 'adjustpan' option?

Tags: android, layout, adjustpan

I made the Layout as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_progress"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/message_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_inputfield"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_inputfield"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0"
                            android:src="@drawable/test" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/test2" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0"
                            android:src="@drawable/test3" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_input"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black">

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the UI is cut when the keyboard is uploaded.

So I solved it with the [adjustpan] option.

This is the same result as I intended.

But I can't even see the "toolbar."

I always want to show "toolbar" at the top.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1DJQ.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m60t.png)

I'll attach the image to the current situation more easily.

If you need any information, please let me know.

Comment: post your whole layout please

Comment: ok, wait.......

Comment: @Faisal I uploaded the layout.

Comment: did you set your toolbar like this: `Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Yes : 
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: @Faisal "Toolbar" operates normally. No problem. What I want is [adjustpan]the cover from the layout.

Comment: try and use adjustResize instead of adjustpan and let me know

Comment: If [adjustResize] is used, the position of the scroll view is moved. No, to be exact, it gets smaller from the bottom up. Can you hold the size reference point of the scroll view down?

Comment: @김주환 have you solved this?